# angularjs: How to inject a dependency into a controller

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, dependency-injection, dependencies

I try to inject a dependency into a controller. I have tried passing  dependencies through an Array, through an inline anonymous function and to use controller.$inject. Nothing works and I'm ready to explode.

Most of the blogs and article that mention dependency injection shows a simple example, where the code passes the $scope and a dependency.... but when I try to replicate the code example nothing works.

There is something that I'm missing. Do I have to instantiate the dependency or how do I pass the dependency?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyViewModel() {
    this.theRightAnswer = 'The answer is 42';
}

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'MyViewModel', function ($scope, MyViewModel) {
        $scope.theAnswer = MyViewModel.theRightAnswer;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either service/ Factory/ provider for that, & then through dependency Injection you can share the functionality in different controllers. Add following line in your code & it'll work as expected.

```
myApp.service('MyViewModel', MyViewModel);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZclGB93Soq5Ce8pFmkQ?p=preview

Comment: Just what I needed :-) 

Based on your suggestions I tried using the factory. It worked.

But what is best practice, service or factory?

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/factory-versus-service Use depending upon situation. But most probably use service even though factory offers little bit more. In typescript way, and in recent version of angular (v2, v4) they preferred  service only.